# How to correct "DNS name does not exist."

Tags: active-directory

I am running AD 2008, which had been working until a few days ago. Suddenly some workstations cannot find resources.

I removed a single workstation and attempted to re-join, which displayed the following error.

```
The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Dire
                                                                                                                              
The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.com

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a

192.168.1.9
```

This makes no sense to me given the following response from nslookup on the DC (192.168.1.9) itself.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>nslookup
Default Server:  fileserver.domain.com
Address:  192.168.1.18

> set type=all
> _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.COM
Server:  fileserver.domain.com
Address:  192.168.1.18

_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.COM SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = domaindc.domain.com
_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.domain.COM SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 389
          svr hostname   = fileserver.domain.com
domaindc.domain.com     internet address = 192.168.1.9
fileserver.domain.com   internet address = 192.168.1.18
> EXIT
Server:  fileserver.domain.com
Address:  192.168.1.18
```

Any ideas on what I might try to fix this issue?

Thanks Larry

Answer (score 0):

•   Remove all the DNS entries from the NIC card settings except primary DNS/DC and reset the NIC.

•   Also, confirm whether your internal DNS server’s IP address is mentioned as the primary DNS IP in the NIC settings instead of ISP’s DNS IP addresses.

•   Please check the event viewer for any information on the incidents and events that lead to this error. And check the network connectivity between the client and DC including all the LDAP and DNS ports.

•   Make sure the time zone and the time is set correctly and synced appropriately between the DC, DNS servers and the clients.

•   Reset the local hosts file to default and then try to domain join once again the client system to domain.